# Possible to get Messages to open tel: links?

Tags: mac, macos, messages

Links that use the [tel: protocol](http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_smartphone-link.htm) open in FaceTime by default on Macs. If, like me, you prefer to text/iMessage rather than call, it would be nice to have them open in Messages by default. I was able to use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to set Messages to the handler for tel: links but it doesn't open a new message to that number, just launches Messages. Anyone know if there's a way to get it to work with AppleScript or something?